Flask cache for Airflow API authentication
I try to implement a JWT token API authentication system where I need to query an LDAP system to get a user/group mapping. I would like to cache that LDAP query result with flask cache (or any other suitable method), since the content of the LDAP query will be pretty static (Only on user / group changes the content will change). So the first request should put the result into cache and all other requests also from different users should use the cache instead. Ideally I would also be able to specify the TTL for the cache.
I was trying with
from airflow.utils.airflow_flask_app import get_airflow_app
from functools import wraps
from flask_caching import Cache

app = get_airflow_app()
cache = Cache()
cache.init_app(app, config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'SimpleCache'})

def auth_current_user():
  members = get_members_of_groups()
  # do some logic here

@cache.cached(timeout=3600)
def get_members_of_groups(groups):
  retval = []
  for group in groups:
    retval.append(ad.get_members_of_group(groupId))
  
  return retval

def requires_authentication(function: T):
  @wraps(function)
  def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
    auth_current_user()
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  
  return cast(T, decorated)

But I fail to initiate Cache() as I have no idea how to get the flask App in Airflow. There is a get_airflow_app() function but using that will result in an error RuntimeError: working outside of application context
